# Angular2 - TypeError: element is undefined

Tags: angular, npm-install, angular2-directives

I was working on an Angular2 project that actually implements 4.0 Angular Libraries.

I was trying to install a new thirdparty component ( angular2-multiselect ) when I notice that it was warning me about some missing dependency like angular/core that for sure I had already installed in the solution.

I decide to **delete de node_modules** , clean the cache (`npm cache clean`) and run again a reinstall for all the packages (`npm install`) in order to download all the dependencies.

The result is that now my application is properly compiled, but when I run it I get lot of those messages "**TypeError: element is undefined**" in the console and lot of components are not loaded properly...

How to come back ok how to resync all ?

Thanks to support

Comment: that means `angular2-multiselect` will work with `Angular 2.0` where as you are using `Angular 4.0` so it warns you. no impact will be there

Comment: Thanks Aravind, so I can ignore the warns... I tried to download again all the packages because the component was not warking but I think that the cause was that I was missing something in the code...
Now, How can I come back and let the application working again?

Comment: undo your changes. if you need more help. update the post with the code and error screenshot